# Object is considered undefined in anonymous function but not before it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I must first disclaim I am modding Game Dev Tycoon, however the source of the game is run beforehand, putting a 'Game' object in global scope before this code runs.

```
new Game({
  conferenceHype: 0
}).gameSize; /* proves that it exists */
(function() {
  var Game, oldGame, oldGameConst;
  oldGameConst = Game;
  oldGame = oldGameConst.prototype; /* fails here because it thinks oldGameConst is undefined */
  Game = function(company) {
    oldGameConst.call(this, company);
    this.company = company;
  };
  Game.prototype = oldGame;
})();
```

Anyone have any ideas on why this would fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>   var Game, oldGame, oldGameConst;
>   oldGameConst = Game;
>   oldGame = oldGameConst.prototype; /* fails here because it thinks oldGameConst is undefined */
> ```

So you:

1. Create some local variables, all of which start out as `undefined`
2. Copy the value of `Game` (`undefined` because you just declared it) to `oldGameConst`)
3. Try to read `oldGameConst.prototype` … which is `undefined` for the above reasons.

If you want to access `Game` from the wider scope: **don't mask it with `var`**.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm an idiot, sorry bout that. (Sometimes using Coffeescript, I forget it can make stupid scoping mistakes, this is one of them :P)